# MS Graph API truncating SingleValueExtendedProperties

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

When issuing queries to the graph API, if I target a specific individual object (e.g. an email) I can use $expand and return full values for `SingleValueExtendedProperties`, however, if I'm issuing a query (e.g. return all emails for the last three days) and using $expand to include the `SingleValueExtendedProperties`, the values of each `SingleValueExtendedProperties` are truncated.

I'd really like to not have to do an N+1 (return all objects then query them one-by-one) as I'm sure I'll hit a throttle at some point, but besides that would be terrible performance.

Anyone know why this would be the case? I cannot find any documentation that tell me this is normal behaviour or if there are query options to change/remove/disable the truncating limit.

I've been using these resources for documentation:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/metadata-for-an-outlook-add-in#get-custom-properties-using-ews-or-rest

Answer (score 0):

MAPI tables always truncated large string and binary properties. To read large properties, you had to open the corresponding item (`IMessage`) and open the property as `IStream` using `IMAPIProp::OpenProperty`.

I would imagine the Exchange Server implementation still uses a similar pattern.

Comment: Oh bollocks. I feel like an N+1 is going to be unavoidable.

Comment: Do you happen to remember the length to which it is truncated?

Comment: For string properties, i is 255 characters.

Comment: Is EWS behaving better?

Comment: I haven't checked EWS and I'm trying to avoid it as XML vs JSON... I'll have a poke at EWS and see what's what.

Comment: EWS will truncate those properties in FindItems, the one big difference is batching in EWS this a lot better then the graph (eg Graph batches are 20 Items max with concurrency limit of 4)

Comment: You can always batch multiple `message/{id}` queries into a single request.

Comment: Try issuing the query with the body in the `select` part or don't apply select at all, this might force the storage to skip optimization and fetch the entire object.